# How to stop blender from generating duplicate vertices on export?

Tags: modeling, export, vertices, gltf

Yes, I know, use *Mesh -> Clean up -> remove by distance*.  I did that, and in blender, it appears as if things are all fine and dandy, I made 3 cubes and made pyramids at the end, total vertex count is 18, makes sense to me.  Export *object* as gltf, and I get... 84 vertices...

[image]

This is the GLTF report

[image]

gltf image, and my blender:

[image]

You can see in the bottom corner, ***18 verts...***.

And for the final touch, here's the output from my tiny_gltf loader c++ program, which outputs vertices, and says the number of vertexes and indexes.

```
{NORMAL: 1}
{POSITION: 0}
{TEXCOORD_0: 2}
COUNT 84
INDCOUNT 96
(1, 1, -1)
(1, 1, -1)
(1, 1, -1)
(1, 1, -1)
(1, 1, -1)
(-1, -1, 1)
(-1, -1, 1)
(-1, -1, 1)
(-1, -1, 1)
(-1, -1, 1)
(-1, -1, 1)
(3, 1, -1)
(3, 1, -1)
(3, 1, -1)
(3, 1, -1)
(3, -1, -1)
(3, -1, -1)
(3, -1, -1)
(3, -1, -1)
(3, 1, 1)
(3, 1, 1)
(3, 1, 1)
(3, 1, 1)
(3, -1, 1)
(3, -1, 1)
(3, -1, 1)
(3, -1, 1)
(1, -1, -1)
(1, -1, -1)
(1, -1, -1)
(1, -1, -1)
(1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 1)
(1, -1, 1)
(1, -1, 1)
(1, -1, 1)
(1, -1, 1)
(1, -1, 1)
(1, -1, 1)
(4, 0, -0)
(4, 0, -0)
(4, 0, -0)
(4, 0, -0)
(-3, 1, 1)
(-3, 1, 1)
(-3, 1, 1)
(-3, 1, 1)
(-3, 1, 1)
(-3, -1, 1)
(-3, -1, 1)
(-3, -1, 1)
(-3, -1, 1)
(-3, 1, -1)
(-3, 1, -1)
(-3, 1, -1)
(-3, 1, -1)
(-3, 1, -1)
(-3, -1, -1)
(-3, -1, -1)
(-3, -1, -1)
(-3, -1, -1)
(-3, -1, -1)
(-1, 1, 1)
(-1, 1, 1)
(-1, 1, 1)
(-1, 1, 1)
(-1, 1, 1)
(-1, 1, 1)
(-1, 1, -1)
(-1, 1, -1)
(-1, 1, -1)
(-1, 1, -1)
(-1, -1, -1)
(-1, -1, -1)
(-1, -1, -1)
(-1, -1, -1)
(-1, -1, -1)
(-1, -1, -1)
(-4, 0, 3.01992e-07)
(-4, 0, 3.01992e-07)
(-4, 0, 3.01992e-07)
(-4, 0, 3.01992e-07)
```

Look at all those duplicates! how do I stop blender from ruining my meshes on export?

This doesn't really answer my question, but I found a temporary work around by copying the vertices on the mesh and deleting the old one.

**Q:** Is this just a really bad bug or something?

Comment: something hidden in the outliner?

Comment: @AllenSimpson I undid what I just did, and there did seem to be like 5 duplicate collections... and 4 meshes... I was on the scene instead of blender file menu.  Yet multiple times I removed duplicate vertices, and when I move the selected object, there's no objects underneath. So I don't understand how these random objects got left around.

Comment: Maybe this https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/addons/io_scene_gltf2.html#meshes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is incorrect to assume the number of glTF verts will equal the number of Blender verts. Each glTF vert has a unique normal for example, while each Blender vert can have a different normal for each poly it is in. Your model uses flat shading and you can see each vertex has multiple normals.

[image: normals]

To handle this there are "duplicate" glTF verts (that have the same position, but different normals). The same thing happens for all other "vertex per poly" data, like UVs.

"Duplicate" verts are inserted only when necessary, so turn off export of anything you don't need—normals, tangents, UVs, vertex colors, materials—to get a smaller glTF vert count.

Comment: This appears to be the issue (though there were 6 extra vertices unaccounted for when I just reran only re-nabling normals)!  I didn't think about the normal aspect of this, indeed for indexing to properly work each normal would need to correspond to a duplicated vertex.