# Merged Vertices won't save when exported. I'm going insane (Blender 2.93)

Tags: modeling, mesh, export, vertices

i'm using a addon to import and export .geo files, only issue that i'm having for the past 4 hours is that Merged Vertices won't save when exported.

I've done it before, i've merged vertices and then exported them without any issue, but today when i opened BLENDER and tried doing so with another .geo model it just won't save the merged vertices, i've tried with all the files that i have, and no matter what i do, when i export them the vertices get split. I can't find an answer online, and i'm literally going insane 'cause of it, i don't know who to ask or where to look for an answer, i can provide the addon that i'm using and the file that i need the merged vertices on, this is my first time using these forums, and it's 3 am, sorry for any mistakes, i just want to merge this vertices man, please help.

Comment: Hello, what do you use to export your model from blender ?

Comment: you should provide as much information as needed so we can help you. And yes, you should provide your add-on and tell us, how you exported your model.

Comment: This is the addon that i'm using  https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/853662197636792342/854215792987734036/geopy-v0.2.9.zip

And here's a geo file in case you don't have one https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/395378528616448006/856425010859343912/GEO_Emblem.geo

What is happening is that, i press M to merge all vertices by distance, they get merged, great, then i go to export my model and when i open up that exported model all the vertices that where previously merged are split, i don't know what to do

Comment: If you got this add-on from a specific source or community, maybe you could ask the question there :  Unless someone here has specific knowledge of this add-on and this file format, we would have to scrub all of the add-on's code and troubleshoot the file in another software which is outside the scope of this site. I understand your frustration but it's almost impossible to help you in the current context. Maybe you could export in another format and open it in your other soft ? .obj, .glb or .dae are often used to export / import 3D files

Comment: Also when exporting, check the right side of the window for settings. Maybe there is something related to merging vertices

Comment: I don't know who made the addon, and the person who gave it to me doesn't either, i'll check the side window, but yeah i don't know what to do if that fails, i'm getting so frustrated by this.
 And no i can't export as .obj because the model loses it's weights and when i try to weight it back it gets all messed up, thanks for your reply though

Comment: It's not all the verts get resplit, it looks like only the ones that have nonsmooth normals. That's normal for lots of formats where, unlike Blender, a vert has only one normal, so a Blender vert with multiple normals needs to be split up into multiple verts with one normal each. I glanced at the code for your addon and that does look like what happens. See also [this Q](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204713/how-to-stop-blender-from-generating-duplicate-vertices-on-export/204766).

Comment: So what should i do? follow that tutorial you linked? cause i'm really just a novice, all i do is move vertices around, change shapes and that's it, i don't know anything about normals or UV mapping, coding, etc

Comment: Why do you care if it splits your verts up?

Comment: When they're not merged, this .geo models get messed up textures ingame, they need to be merged for the texture to look as it should

Comment: There's no reason spliting verts would mess up textures, there's some other thing you need to fix. I doubt you can stop it splitting anyway, GPUs need verts split, and I assume the addon author knew what they were doing. But this really isn't a Blender question.

Comment: It does mess up textures, and i have proof of it, it has happened and it'll keep happening if i can't find a solution.
 And i don't know if the author knew what they where doing, this are all files from a really old game with messy code, i thank your reply, but i know that this models *need* to have merged vertices