# Export fbx without duplicating vertices

Tags: export, .fbx

Reference issue: [How to stop blender from generating duplicate vertices on export?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204713/how-to-stop-blender-from-generating-duplicate-vertices-on-export). The answer says "so turn off export of anything you don't need" - doesn't say how to do this

I have a model with 14 vertices which become 54 after export in fbx. How to disable writing any vertex data (except position) into fbx? I just need convex geometry **without** uv, normals or something

What I've tried so far:

Export fbx window - no such option

Python export api: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.export_scene.html?highlight=bpy%20ops%20export_scene#bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx
No such option or something close to it. Its wild because e.g. OBJ export options has such stuff

Maybe there is python api to manually remove vertices data collections?

---

I just found out how to do this:

1. Use *Shade Smooth* in *Object Mode*.
2. Remove UVs from Properties > Object Data Properties > Remove UV map*.

Is there any other way without messing up with your geometry?