# GLTF exports extra vertices

Tags: export, vertices, gltf

When exporting a **smooth-shaded default cube** as .GLTF, Blender adds **duplicate vertices**. The GLTF file has 14 vertices, when there should be only 8 (smooth-shaded, so shared normals).

When I export to **.OBJ or .DAE**, no duplicate vertices are added. They both **correctly hold only 8 vertices**.

On further investigation, GLTF does this for every smooth-shaded model. It adds extra vertices where other formats don't. But **this is wrong, as OpenGL does not need this extra data** to render a smooth shaded cube. Duplicate verts are **only required for flat-shaded meshes**. In the case of a flat-shaded cube, Blender correctly exports to GLTF with 24 vertices.

---

**To recreate:** set default cube to shade smooth, and export. That's it.

---

EDIT: You've **closed a question because you don't understand it**. The "duplicate" question is answered on the basis of "Your model uses flat shading and you can see each vertex has multiple normals."

Whereas I am specifically referring to a smooth-shaded mesh (which means normals are shared, so no duplicates, no need for GLTF to repeat vertices beyond the 8 that make up a cube).

**TLDR: FLAT SHADING VS SMOOTH SHADING** is why they're different. Please reopen the question.

Comment: This is a duplicate question.  See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/204766/18161

Comment: I focused my answer on your **To recreate:** setup but @emackey is right, its a duplicate.

Comment: Hello, KobeSystem.. it does look as though this is a duplicate, and fair to close. If for any reason the other answer isn't working for you, edit to point out the difference, and we can reopen for you.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I've read that "duplicate" question, and I specifically addressed that answer in my question, when I specify smooth shading vs flat?

Comment: The issue happens with the default cube, but not with one created manually from extruding a plane. Maybe a bug, might be worth to use the menu Help > Report A Bug to be sure.

Comment: @L0Lock no bugs here. If you extrude a plane, the generated UV Map is different from the one which is generated when adding a default cube. For the extruded plane, Blender holds 8 unique vertex/uv combinations, for the default cube there are 14 uniques. The export is correct.

Comment: @L0Lock Ah thank you. Interesting, and unfortunately, this problem appears to also be present when exporting an icosphere and uv sphere. And I suspect it is that way for all the Blender primitives.

Comment: @taiyo Why would the default cube have 14 vertices? It's just a cube, unless you're saying it has hidden extra properties or something?

Comment: @KobeSystem Because i double checked with a script, i'll update my answer.

Comment: @taiyo Problem with that is .OBJ and .DAE export the default cube (correctly) with 8 vertices. So that means the default cube has 8 vertices. Also the Blender scene statistics say the default cube has 8 vertices. So I'm not sure where 14 comes from

Comment: Of course it has 8 vertices, it's a cube. But it has also an **uv mapping** active, that's the whole point here. If you export the cube to .obj with _Geometry > UV Coordinates_ ticked, you will find 14 `vt` entries in the .obj file. The file formats are different in how they store the necessary data. If you want the glTF to store only 8 vertices, you need to tell that the glTF implementers. This is not Blenders playground.

Comment: @KobeSystem i see your confusion now. I am not saying the cube in Blender has 14 vertices, but the glTF export has 14 vertices (when the UVs are exported too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the glTF export dialog, untick *Data > Mesh > UVs* and you get your 8 vertices and normals. The other option is to remove the automatically created *UVMap* under the object's *Data > UV Maps* panel (then *Data > Mesh > UVs* can stay ticked).

**Edit:**
*Why does the glTF file for the default cube has 14 vertices?*

Open Blender, set the shading of the default cube to *Shade Smooth* and run this script:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]

# print all vertices with their uvs defining the cube
pairs = []
for face in obj.data.polygons:
    for vert_index, loop_index in zip(face.vertices, face.loop_indices):
        uv_coords = obj.data.uv_layers.active.data[loop_index].uv
        pairs.append((face.index, vert_index, uv_coords.x, uv_coords.y))
        print("face: %i, vertex: %i, uvs: %f, %f" % pairs[-1])

# print all vertices with their uvs which are unique
# and therefore must be stored
uniques = []
for pair in pairs:
    found = False
    for other in uniques:
        if pair[1] == other[1] and pair[2] == other[2] and pair[3] == other[3]:
            found = True
            break
    if not found:
        uniques.append(pair)
        
print(len(uniques), uniques)
```

This gives (*Window > Toggle System Console*):

```
face: 0, vertex: 0, uvs: 0.625000, 0.500000
face: 0, vertex: 4, uvs: 0.875000, 0.500000
face: 0, vertex: 6, uvs: 0.875000, 0.750000
face: 0, vertex: 2, uvs: 0.625000, 0.750000
face: 1, vertex: 3, uvs: 0.375000, 0.750000
face: 1, vertex: 2, uvs: 0.625000, 0.750000
face: 1, vertex: 6, uvs: 0.625000, 1.000000
face: 1, vertex: 7, uvs: 0.375000, 1.000000
face: 2, vertex: 7, uvs: 0.375000, 0.000000
face: 2, vertex: 6, uvs: 0.625000, 0.000000
face: 2, vertex: 4, uvs: 0.625000, 0.250000
face: 2, vertex: 5, uvs: 0.375000, 0.250000
face: 3, vertex: 5, uvs: 0.125000, 0.500000
face: 3, vertex: 1, uvs: 0.375000, 0.500000
face: 3, vertex: 3, uvs: 0.375000, 0.750000
face: 3, vertex: 7, uvs: 0.125000, 0.750000
face: 4, vertex: 1, uvs: 0.375000, 0.500000
face: 4, vertex: 0, uvs: 0.625000, 0.500000
face: 4, vertex: 2, uvs: 0.625000, 0.750000
face: 4, vertex: 3, uvs: 0.375000, 0.750000
face: 5, vertex: 5, uvs: 0.375000, 0.250000
face: 5, vertex: 4, uvs: 0.625000, 0.250000
face: 5, vertex: 0, uvs: 0.625000, 0.500000
face: 5, vertex: 1, uvs: 0.375000, 0.500000
14 [(0, 0, 0.625, 0.5), (0, 4, 0.875, 0.5), (0, 6, 0.875, 0.75), (0, 2, 0.625, 0.75), (1, 3, 0.375, 0.75), (1, 6, 0.625, 1.0), (1, 7, 0.375, 1.0), (2, 7, 0.375, 0.0), (2, 6, 0.625, 0.0), (2, 4, 0.625, 0.25), (2, 5, 0.375, 0.25), (3, 5, 0.125, 0.5), (3, 1, 0.375, 0.5), (3, 7, 0.125, 0.75)]
```

As one can see, there are 14 unique uv'ed vertices to keep track of.

**Edit2:** note that there are only 8 vertices as it should be. A vertex (representing only a position) is not the same as an uv'ed vertex (representing a position *and* an uv attribute).

Do the same with an extruded plane, this will give this output:

```
face: 0, vertex: 0, uvs: 0.000000, 0.000000
face: 0, vertex: 2, uvs: 0.000000, 1.000000
face: 0, vertex: 3, uvs: 1.000000, 1.000000
face: 0, vertex: 1, uvs: 1.000000, 0.000000
face: 1, vertex: 5, uvs: 0.000000, 0.000000
face: 1, vertex: 6, uvs: 1.000000, 0.000000
face: 1, vertex: 7, uvs: 1.000000, 1.000000
face: 1, vertex: 4, uvs: 0.000000, 1.000000
face: 2, vertex: 3, uvs: 1.000000, 1.000000
face: 2, vertex: 2, uvs: 0.000000, 1.000000
face: 2, vertex: 4, uvs: 0.000000, 1.000000
face: 2, vertex: 7, uvs: 1.000000, 1.000000
face: 3, vertex: 0, uvs: 0.000000, 0.000000
face: 3, vertex: 1, uvs: 1.000000, 0.000000
face: 3, vertex: 6, uvs: 1.000000, 0.000000
face: 3, vertex: 5, uvs: 0.000000, 0.000000
face: 4, vertex: 1, uvs: 1.000000, 0.000000
face: 4, vertex: 3, uvs: 1.000000, 1.000000
face: 4, vertex: 7, uvs: 1.000000, 1.000000
face: 4, vertex: 6, uvs: 1.000000, 0.000000
face: 5, vertex: 2, uvs: 0.000000, 1.000000
face: 5, vertex: 0, uvs: 0.000000, 0.000000
face: 5, vertex: 5, uvs: 0.000000, 0.000000
face: 5, vertex: 4, uvs: 0.000000, 1.000000
8 [(0, 0, 0.0, 0.0), (0, 2, 0.0, 1.0), (0, 3, 1.0, 1.0), (0, 1, 1.0, 0.0), (1, 5, 0.0, 0.0), (1, 6, 1.0, 0.0), (1, 7, 1.0, 1.0), (1, 4, 0.0, 1.0)]
```

Now there are only 8 unique uv'ed vertices, because the created uv map is different. As image (for the default cube, Blender created a nice cube net, but for the extruded plane all sides have the same uv square):

[image]

Therefore, the following export glTF behaviour can be observed:

```
Shade Smooth                 | Default Cube | Extruded Plane
----------------------------------------------------------
Data > Mesh > UVs ticked     |    14        |      8
Data > Mesh > UVs unticked   |     8        |      8
```

In the glTF file the information can be found under:

```
{
    ...
    "accessors":[
        {
            "bufferView":0,
            ...
            "count":14,   <-- here
            ...
        },
        ...
}
```

Note: the other [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204713/how-to-stop-blender-from-generating-duplicate-vertices-on-export/204766#204766) states

> To handle this there are "duplicate" glTF verts (that have the same position, but different normals). The same thing happens for all other "vertex per poly" data, like UVs.
> "Duplicate" verts are inserted only when necessary, so turn off export of anything you don't need—normals, tangents, UVs, vertex colors, materials—to get a smaller glTF vert count.

which is why this question is considered a duplicate.

Comment: I've done this and still the GLTF file has 14 vertices and 14 normals. Also I'm exporting to GLTF (not GLB).

Comment: @KobeSystem I've exported to glTF too. Which Blender version are you using?

Comment: Great, thanks. I see now. Your image of the two UV maps side by side cleared things up for me. The other question was focused on duplicates due to flat-shading/extra normals, but you're right the answer mentions that it affects all attributes. However your side by side UV maps helped me to properly think that through.