Same mesh/submesh has many more vertices after export and reimport to Blender
How is it possible that the same submesh after exporting to .glb(gLTF 2.0) and re-importing into Blender has MANY more vertices e.g. before export was 55068 vertices and after export and re-import becomes 179722?
No Modifiers, just move(not join) submeshes into one "Collection".

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204713/how-to-stop-blender-from-generating-duplicate-vertices-on-export
